# Is it possible to connect ASP.NET Core with AngularJS(~1.6.7v)

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am trying to make ASP.NET core project with AngularJS(v1.6.7) to work together, with a possibility to unplug/change the AngularJS part, if I need to migrate to Angular(v2). But the problem is that there aren't any tutorials using AngularJS(v1.6), how to do that? I am not sure if I need to specify any code or structure here, because it is pretty much **one** controller for ASP.NET Core and in the **wwwroot** folder consists of **app**/../Controllers & Views. Do I need to change/add something to Program, Startup classes or change something for Angular part? At the moment I am having problems with routing.
The only thing what I have is this AngularJS Generator - https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular , what can be used to generate the basic template for the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup of Angular 1.x is the same and works fine regardless if you're using ASP.NET Core or for instance ASP.NET MVC for the back-end.

I wrote a comprehensive tutorial years ago explaining how to setup Angular 1.x for an ASP.NET MVC back-end, I think you can pretty much follow it, save for some small tweaks to the back-end:

https://sirarsalih.com/2013/10/31/embedding-angularjs-in-asp-net-mvc/

There is also in the article the added bonus of showing how to write unit tests for your front-end.

Good luck!